# dropping NA in a list

Tags: r, list, na

After many tries and failures, I bring the following data:

```
canada <- c(100, 80, 100, 100, 20)
korea <- c(100, "", 100, "", "")
brazil <- c(100, 90, 100, 30, 30)
fruit <- rbind(canada, korea, brazil)
colnames(fruit) <- c("apple", "orange", "banana", "grape", "kiwi")
fruit
```

I want it to look like this:

```
> price("korea")
Thank you, StackOverflow, for the delicious apple and banana.
```

So I tried the following:

```
price <- function(val){
  val <- tolower(val)
  myrow <- fruit[val,]
  nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)

  name.min <- names(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  name.max <- sapply(seq_along(myrow), 
                     function(x, n, i) {paste0(n[i])},
                     x=myrow, n=names(na.omit(which(myrow == max(myrow)))))
  name.max[length(name.max)] <- paste0("and ", name.max[na.omit(length(name.max))])
  name.max <- paste(name.max, collapse = ", ")

  cat(paste0("My fruits have a NAsty taste at the end: ", name.max))
}
```

Which printed the following:

```
> price("korea")
My fruits have a NAsty taste at the end: apple, banana, NA, NA, and NA
```

Am I using the `na.omit` function wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `seq_along` `myrow`, and use that to access `n`, but `n` has fewer elements than `myrow` because you remove all those elements whose value is smaller than `max(myrow)`

If you change that, you will get only those where the value is equal to the max:

```
price <- function(val){

  val <- tolower(val)
  myrow <- fruit[val,]
  nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)

  name.min <- names(myrow)[which.min(c(myrow))]
  name.max <- sapply(seq_along(na.omit(which(myrow == max(myrow)))), 
                     function(x, n, i) {paste0(n[i])},
                     x=myrow, n=names(na.omit(which(myrow == max(myrow)))))
  name.max[length(name.max)] <- paste0("and ", name.max[na.omit(length(name.max))])
  name.max <- paste(name.max, collapse = ", ")

  cat(paste0("My fruits don't have a NAsty taste at the end: ", name.max))
}
```

That said, it's a bit unclear what you want the function to do. I'm sure there's a more elegant way to do it. For example, why do you calculate `name.min` and never use it?

If you just want the column names where the value is equal to the max value, this is much more readable and efficient:

```
name.max <- names(myrow[myrow == max(myrow)])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You're correct in your assessment. This function is a part of a bulkier script, and I do use name.min for other uses. I figured that I can apply the trick learned in name.max to name.min, so I asked only one part of the question because I'll have to put in the work as well!

Comment: Right, but sometimes knowing what it is that you need wil lead to simpler solutions. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks! I will take your comment into consideration for next time! By the way, I tried the `name.max <- names(myrow[myrow == max(myrow)])` before, but this only lists names without the commas!

Comment: Yes, you will need to add the commas. It only replaces the line `name.max <- sapply(...`

Answer (score 1):

I think you could simply wrap your vector myrow in na.omit.

```
as.vector(na.omit(myrow))
```

For example

```
as.vector(na.omit(c(NA, 2,2,3)))
[1] 2 2 3
```

So, if you just want to get your name.min or name.max, you could do as follows.

```
name.min <- names(myrow)[which.min(na.omit(myrow))]
name.max <- names(myrow)[which.max(na.omit(myrow))]
```

This way, you could omit the sapply() call and replace as follows.

```
price <- function(val){
  val <- tolower(val)
  myrow <- fruit[val,]
  nation <- tools::toTitleCase(val)
  #
  if (min(myrow, na.rm = TRUE) == max(myrow, na.rm = TRUE)) {
    name.max <-  as.vector(na.omit(names(myrow)[myrow == max(myrow, na.rm = TRUE)]))
  } else {
    name.max <- names(myrow)[which.max(na.omit(myrow))]
  }
  cat(paste0("My fruits have a NAsty taste at the end: ", paste(name.max, collapse = ", ")))
}
```

Result should be as expected.

```
# data
canada <- as.numeric(c(100, 80, 100, 100, 20))
korea <- as.numeric(c(100, "", 100, "", ""))
brazil <- as.numeric(c(100, 90, 100, 30, 30))
fruit <- rbind(canada, korea, brazil)
colnames(fruit) <- c("apple", "orange", "banana", "grape", "kiwi")

# run
price("korea")
My fruits have a NAsty taste at the end: apple, banana
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work. Maybe I am using it wrong ...cat(paste0("Fruits have a NAsty taste at the end: ", as.vector(na.omit(name.max))))
 } 
> price("korea")
Fruits have a NAsty taste at the end: apple, banana, NA, NA, and NA

Comment: The edited version worked! It's amazing. Thank you so much for putting in the time and effort. I really appreciate it a lot : )

Comment: You're welcome. I just wanted to expand on the idea of using na.omit tp address this issue. As always, there are several ways to tackle the same problem and it's nice to have a panel of choices... :-)